Why no profiler.h in the conan gperftools latest versions?
Starting from version 2.11, the file gperftools/profiler.h disappears. https://conan.io/center/recipes/gperftools?version=2.16
How to profile the application of recent versions if I want to install a library from a Conan?

I'd guess you need to enable the profiling options https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/0a2994175619de0fc99880b97a6e139828dd3dcc/recipes/gperftools/all/conanfile.py#L28

You can use the package options and build from source: conan install --requires=gperftools/2.11 -o "&:build_cpu_profiler=True" -o "&:build_heap_profiler=True" --build=gperftools
In order to understand what options are available, you can reach the gperftools Conan recipe: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/gperftools/all/conanfile.py#L44

profiler.h is for cpu profiler part (not heap checker as seemingly suggested by link above). I am gperftool maintainer and know nothing about conan. Can someone perhaps consider making sure that cpu profiler is enabled by default in this conan thingy? As for original question, if cpu profiling thing is one-off, then you can always build libprofiler.so with usual mean and LD_PRELOAD it, bypassing conan thingy.
